# How to tell if a memory address has been free'd?

Tags: c

Here is a basic block of code I have to extract a regex match and then free the malloc'd match:

```
// malloc new substring and update bufferptr (here instead of passing the 
// buffer we pass a pointer with an address to be updated
PCRE2_UCHAR *bufferptr;
printf("Stack address: %p | Pointer value: %p\n", &bufferptr, bufferptr);
pcre2_substring_get_bynumber(match_data, 1, &bufferptr, &buffer_size);
printf("Extracted substring: '%s' | Code size: %zu | Stack address: %p | Pointer value: %p\n", bufferptr, buffer_size, &bufferptr, bufferptr);
pcre2_substring_free(bufferptr);
printf("Extracted substring: '%s' | Code size: %zu | Stack address: %p | Pointer value: %p\n", bufferptr, buffer_size, &bufferptr, bufferptr);
```

It currently prints out something like this:

```
Stack address: 0x7ffeedbce5e8 | Pointer value: 0x0
Extracted substring: 'lo' | Code size: 2 | Stack address: 0x7ffeedbce5e8 | Pointer value: 0x7f88a8402c98
// after being free'd
Extracted substring: 'lo' | Code size: 2 | Stack address: 0x7ffeedbce5e8 | Pointer value: 0x7f88a8402c98
```

I believe that the second time I print is printing a pointer that has been free'd, but it returns the same thing since it has not yet been overwritten. Is there a way to confirm this? That is, how can I tell if an area of memory has been freed or not?

Comment: You can't tell, as with many instances of undefined behaviour in C. Referring to an object whose lifetime has ended is UB, and that includes dynamically allocated objects whose memory has been freed. Since the standard doesn't prescribe a behaviour for these cases, the implementation could even lie to you by trying to make you believe the object still exists. Caveat programador.

Comment: @rici thanks, that makes things a bit tricky, and it seems like a lot of bugs can pop up that way where things "look ok" but it's actually UB.

Comment: There are languages which insert run-time checks in order to protect you from this sort of thing. And there are languages with garbage collectors which kind of save you the trouble of managing memory. C's focus is on running correct programs quickly, so it does neither of the above. But you're under no obligation to use it. :-) (And yes, a good number of known vulnerabilities have UB at their core. So it's a thing.) If you're going to program in C, now is a good time to develop some good habits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way in-program to verify that a particular piece of memory has been freed.

Once memory has been freed, the value of any pointer that was pointing to that memory becomes **indeterminate**.  Attempting to do dereference a pointer to freed memory triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to verify that you've freed memory that you're supposed to you need to use an external tool such as valgrind.  It will tell you if you have a memory leak or if you attempt to access memory you shouldn't.

Comment: thanks, I think valgrind is the way to go here. I tried running it to make sure things were free'd and it was confirmed. For example, I got a few 'errors' such as: `==5636== Invalid read of size 16` from the print statement. And also, if I remove that free-statement I get another error in valgrind that says `definitely lost: 48 bytes in 1 blocks` .